# Swapping items in a grid

Tags: java, android, touch, andengine, game-engine

I have a 6x6 grid of sprites. I am trying to create the following behaviour but I seem to have issues with the selectedCell not resetting. It seems to keep a selected cell randomly after the swap but the select and deselect the same cell seems to work.

1. When a user taps a cell it should become the selected cell.
2. When a user taps the cell again the selected cell should be reset to null (or nothing)
3. When a user taps a cell then taps another different cell those cells should be swapped. (by means of swapping the objects properties. after this the selected cell should be reset.)

Is there any obvious mistake in the way I am implementing this functionality or is there a simpler way to do this?

The cells have the following OnTouchEventMethod:

```
    @Override
public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
        switch(pSceneTouchEvent.getAction()) {
         case TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
             this.setScale(1.2f);
             this.setZIndex(999);
             this.gGrid.sortChildren();
             Log.d("TOUCH", "ACTION_DOWN");
             break;
         case TouchEvent.ACTION_UP:
             this.setScale(1.0f);
             this.setZIndex(1);
             this.gGrid.sortChildren();
             Log.d("TOUCH", "ACTION_UP");

                 gGrid.cellTouchEvent(this);

             break;
         case TouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            break;
             }

    return false;
}
```

This code will call the cellTouchEvent() method in the grid object

```
    /**
 * called when a touch event is registered on a Grid Cell
 */
public void cellTouchEvent(GameGridCell cell) {
    if(cell.isGGCellVisible()) {

        if(this.selectedCell==null) {
            this.setSelectedCell(cell);//sets the selected cell as one is not set
            Log.d("TEST", "SET SELECTED CELL");
        } else {

            if(this.selectedCell == cell) {
                Log.d("TEST", "UNSET SELECTED CELLS");
                this.setSelectedCellToNull(); //Set selected cell to null as it was pressed twice
            } else if (this.selectedCell != cell) {
                this.swapCells(this.selectedCell, cell); //Swap the two cells
                this.setSelectedCellToNull(); //Ensure selected cell is set to null after swap
            }

        }

    } else if(!cell.isGGCellVisible()) {
        cell.showCellContents(); //Show the contents of the cell as it is not visible
    }
}
```

Finally this is the code to do the actual swapping of cells

```
/**
 * Swaps the two cells passed in as parameters
 */
public void swapCells(GameGridCell cellA, GameGridCell cellB) {
    //First swap the locations in the gridItemsArray
    this.gridItemsArray.setValueAt(cellA.getGGCellID(), cellB);
    this.gridItemsArray.setValueAt(cellB.getGGCellID(), cellA);

    //Save cell A variables
    float x = cellA.getX();
    float y = cellA.getY();
    int id = cellA.getGGCellID();
    int type = cellA.getGGCellType();
    boolean visible = cellA.isVisible();

    //Set cell A to cells B variables
    cellA.setX(cellB.getX());
    cellA.setY(cellB.getY());
    cellA.setGGCellID(cellB.getGGCellID());
    cellA.setGGCellType(cellB.getGGCellType());
    cellA.setVisible(cellB.isVisible());

    //set cell B to saved variables
    cellB.setX(x);
    cellB.setY(y);
    cellB.setGGCellID(id);
    cellB.setGGCellType(type);
    cellB.setVisible(visible);

    //Update the cell ID text
    cellA.updateCellIDText();
    cellB.updateCellIDText();

    this.sortChildren(); //Finally sort the children
}
```

As the comment asks here are the methods for setting the selected cell

```
    /**
 * @return the selectedCell
 */
public GameGridCell getSelectedCell() {
    return selectedCell;
}

/**
 * @param selectedCell the selectedCell to set
 */
public void setSelectedCell(GameGridCell selectedCell) {
    if(selectedCell==null) {
        this.selectedCell=null;
    } else {
        this.selectedCell = selectedCell;
    }       
    this.gameLevel.updateCellIDText();
}

/**
 * @param selectedCell the selectedCell to set
 */
public void setSelectedCellToNull() {
    this.selectedCell=null;
    this.gameLevel.updateCellIDText();
}
```

Comment: If you have problem with selected cell not resetting, please also post code for your resetting method.

Comment: i have added the methods to the question

Comment: Also, please clarify this sentence: "It seems to keep a selected cell randomly after the swap". What do you mean keep? Randomly? Notice is it really random or is there a pattern...

Comment: I cant really see any pattern to it. Sometimes it will not reset the selected cell to null and as I keep tapping each cell it will switch with the previous. However if I double tap a cell it will always reset.

Comment: I tried changing the method call to the ACTION_DOWN event - same issue. I did however notice that there seems to be a double event happening - By that i mean a double ACTION_DOWN which may explain why as the selected cell may be getting reset then set.

Comment: Try using return true instead of break statements in your onAreaTouched actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your touch event for actions, instead of using break, return true:

```
case TouchEvent.ACTION_UP:
         this.setScale(1.0f);
         this.setZIndex(1);
         this.gGrid.sortChildren();
         Log.d("TOUCH", "ACTION_UP");

             gGrid.cellTouchEvent(this);

         //don't use break 
         //break;
         //instead return true, which means you've handled touch
         return true;
```

Do it for all actions that you handle.

Comment: excellent - that seems to have resolved my issues with the touch events!